# Datetime column gives unexpected format in python for Postgres table

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, datetime

This is the query i am trying to run in a python file

```
cur.execute(f"(select data_end_time from table;))
records = cur.fetchall()")
print(records[0])
```

This is the Output i am getting

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 17, 0)
```

Expected output

```
2020-07-06 17:00:00
```

records[0] contains value datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 17, 0) and is of type tuple

Comment: This doesnt answer my question ..

Comment: records[0] contains value datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 17, 0),and is of type tuple

Comment: Please clarify: do you mean it's a tuple with a datetime object inside?

Comment: records[0] is of type tuple with datetime inside it

Comment: did you try `records[0][0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use datetime.strftime for converting datetime object into string

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 6, 17, 0)

print(x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#output
'2020-07-06 17:00:00'
```

Comment: Din work ..Error :'tuple' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: try x[0]..strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: records[0][0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') worked ..